# jQuery - populate and remove from one div to another

Tags: jquery

I am trying to remove elements from a populated list to append to another list( div). I have the functionality set but I want elements selected from the list on the left to disappear when moved into the list on the right. 
Using $( ".choosefromlist" ).hide();  just made the entire lists all hide. I just want the elements that you selected on the left to disappear when selected. Bonus if you can tell me how to get rid of the li nav dots on the right as well!

Here's my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/9vtnq8fk/

```
//populate the chosenlist
    $(document).on('click', '.choosefromlist', function () {
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var answerCount = $('.answer .chosenlist li').length;
        if(answerCount<3){
             $('.chosenlist').append('<li class="choice" name="' + name     + '" value="' + id + '">' + name + '</li>');
// make this link unclickable
    $(this).removeClass('choosefromlist');
   }
});
//remove options from the chosenlist
$(document).on('click', '.choice', function () {
var name = $(this).attr('value');
$(this).remove();   // make the original link clickable again
$('#' + name).addClass('choosefromlist');
```

});

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest least magical way is to set the css to display:none. You will also want to set it back to block when you add the class back. The code would look like

```
//populate the chosenlist
$(document).on('click', '.choosefromlist', function () {
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var answerCount = $('.answer .chosenlist li').length;
    if(answerCount<3){
        $('.chosenlist').append('<li class="choice" name="' + name + '" value="' + id + '">' + name + '</li>');
    // make this link unclickable
        $(this).removeClass('choosefromlist').css('display', 'none');
    }
});

//remove options from the chosenlist
$(document).on('click', '.choice', function () {
    var name = $(this).attr('value');
    $(this).remove();
   // make the original link clickable again
    $('#' + name).addClass('choosefromlist').css('display', 'block');
});
```

The preferred way would be to create a class that hides it then add/remove the class, like

## CSS

```
.hide {
  display: none;
}
li{
  list-style:none;
}
```

## JS

```
$(this).removeClass('choosefromlist').addClass('hide');
...
$('#' + name).addClass('choosefromlist').removeClass('hide');
```

Edit: updated to disable `li` bullets for "bonus points" :)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! So you use .css('display', 'none') and block instead of hide.

Comment: Using `.hide()` and `.show()` is actually better in my opinion than changing with  `.css` because it's the "jQuery way," but better still would be to use a class, as I showed in my update.